# How could an element not in two sets be an element of their union with a third set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

In this problem, I don't understand why statement (f) is true.
Since it is possible that ***`x`*** is neither in **`A`** nor in **`B`**. And since it is not certain that **`x`** belongs to **`C`**, how is it possible to know that what statement (f) says is true? It possible that **`x`** belongs to none of these three sets and then the statement would be false.

[The problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pALS5.png)

[The solution provided by the book.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNpSc.png)

Comment: It says "for some non-empty set", which means, that (in this world) there exists at least one set $C$ such that $x \in A\cup C$ and $x \in B \cup C$. I don't see any problem taking $C=\{x\}$ which makes the statement true.

Comment: Let $C=S$......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just an ambiguity of wording. "For some nonempty set $C$ ..." means "There exists some nonempty set $C$ such that ..."

(It does not mean that the statement holds true for "just any" nonempty set $C$, as you seem to point out.)

To see it is true in this case, take $C=S$, or $C = \{x\}$.

Comment: What ambiguity of wording? I don't see any ambiguity.

Comment: Especially if English is not your first language, basically any English sentence is ambiguous. The difference between "any" and "some" is subtle for learners.